# Extend database for group/collaborative messaging

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, chat, messaging

I have following database schema for the messaging app I'm creating:-

Table Name:- `conversation_threads`

```
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| conversation_id | label | members |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| 1               | TEST  | 1,2     |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| 2               | XYZ   | 4,1     |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

Table Name:- `messages`

```
+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| message_id | message        | sender_id | conversation_id | created_at          |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 1          | Hello          | 1         | 1               | 2017-09-12 09:00:00 |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2          | Hi             | 2         | 1               | 2017-09-12 09:02:00 |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 3          | Hey!           | 4         | 2               | 2017-09-12 08:16:00 |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Table Name:- `message_users`

```
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| mu_id    | message_id  | user_id | status |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| 1        | 1           | 1       | READ   |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| 2        | 1           | 2       | UNREAD |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| 3        | 2           | 2       | READ   |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| 4        | 2           | 1       | UNREAD |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| 5        | 3           | 4       | READ   |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| 6        | 3           | 1       | UNREAD |
+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
```

This schema works quite fine with One-to-one messaging.

But now I want to introduce more than 2 users in a single conversation so that all the 3 or 4 or more people can collaborate and discuss things.

What I am facing problem with is if I add another user in the `members` field in conversation threads - he gets accessibility to read all the messages present in that particular conversation thread since the beginning - although he was added late into the conversation.

Please provide me a solution on how to tackle this particular problem.

Hope my question is not too broad.

Comment: Not too broad, but probably asked and answered many times before.  It looks OK except for that CSV data in the `conversation_threads` table.  Get rid of it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - So if I remove the `members` column - do I need to introduce another table for storing `conversation_thread_members` ? And how do I approach to solve the problem of showing a thread member only those messages which were communicated after he joined the conversation?

Comment: Ah I see! So if I add another user - he'll simply get only those messages for which his user ID is assigned in the `message_users` table. So if I need to broadcast a small special (highlighted) message like "User A joined the conversation" - I'd simply have to store it as a message with some extra information that this is a "Highlight" message. Maybe a flag field containing its type. So for normal it'd be "TEXT" message, for this one it'd be "HIGHLIGHT"

Comment: I don't follow your design exactly, but if you break out each CSV value into a separate row you will generally have a much easier time querying.

Comment: Ok - I'd break the CSV value into a separate table with each member ID in a separate row. I guess you're right about the fact that this will make querying easier.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you schema relation you have just to put members like you did

```
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| conversation_id | label | members |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| 1               | TEST  | 1,2,3,4 |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: I didn't talk about CSV i am talking about storing data to mysql :(. it look like a simple output from a shell, and members column seem to be a varchar type.

Comment: Yes - `members` is a VARCHAR type column.